# HTML5 video doesn't play until source update

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, video-streaming, html5-video

I've got a HTML5 player, which is a part of my mobile (cordova) app:

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" id="video-1" src="/mnt/sdcard/xyz-media/xyz.mp4?param=8zw6y" preload="none">
  <source src="/mnt/sdcard/xyz-media/xyz.mp4?param=8zw6y" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

`?param=` in the and was added because of known Chrome bug caused by loading multiple videos.

So I have in my code also `canplaythrough` event:

```
var videoWrapper = document.getElementById('video-1');

videoWrapper.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function(){
  videoWrapper.play();
});
```

But video never plays. When I try to execute it manually it doesn't work either, but when I manually reload `src` attribute and then try play - it works:

```
var src = document.getElementById('video-1').getAttribude('src');
document.getElementById('video-1').setAttribute('src', src);
document.getElementById('video-1').play();
```

Why video doesn't play without this refresh? Please help.

Comment: In your code your are giving `src` twice and id use in javascript is `video-1` while in html it's `video-2`

Comment: @ricky that different id attribute was my mistake while writing this question - sorry, I've now fixed it. Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the problem is on `preload` property. You have configured it as `none` so browser doesn't load video when page loading. Using `auto` should works.

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" id="video-1" preload="auto">
  <source src="/mnt/sdcard/xyz-media/xyz.mp4?param=8zw6y" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `src` at wrong place in video tag, at that place you can use controls.

See this link :
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp.

Get more video settings from this link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

I hope this will help you.

Also make sure that you are writting correct `#id` for video tag.

```
var videoWrapper = document.getElementById('video-1');
```

or

```
var videoWrapper = document.getElementById('video-2');// Correct One
```

Thanks

Comment: I've fixed that div id in the question - that was my mistake while writing question, in my production code id's are correct - sorry for that :)

Comment: after changing `src` usage problem still persists. And my manual solution still works too.

Comment: Hello Sir, 
Please confirm that your video type and the source type="video/mp4" should be same.

if you are adding any youtube video then you must have to get mp4 video link.

<source src="creativevortexlogo.mp4" type="video/mp4">

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure about it - it is locally stored mp4 video.

Comment: Hello Sir, 
Please use the demo script for video

<video preload="auto" autoplay controls>
  <source src="your_video_path" type="video/mp4">
</video>